# Instance of typeclass for types of kind * where a type of kind * -> * is expected

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to create an instance of the scalaz's [`IsEmpty`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.4/scalaz_2.11-7.1.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.IsEmpty) typeclass for `String`. This is what I've got so far:

```
implicit val stringIsEmpty = new IsEmpty[({ type t[+A] = String })#t] {
  def isEmpty[A](fa: String) = ???
  def empty[A] = ???
  def plus[A](a: String, b: => String) = ???
}

def f[F[_]: IsEmpty, A](fa: F[A]): F[A] = fa
```

Now, `String` is of kind `*` whereas `IsEmpty[F]` expects `F` to be of kind `* -> *`, hence the type lambda `f[+A] = String`.

This works, but only if the string is typed as `t`, that is:

```
// doesn't compile
f("hello")

// compiles if I extract `t` into a type alias and annotate the string with it
type t[+A] = String
implicit val stringIsEmpty = new IsEmpty[t] { /** **/ }

f("hello": t[Nothing])
```

Is there any way to implement `IsEmpty` in such a way that I can then apply `f` to a string as normal?

Comment: This seems to relate to this issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712 . Isn't it? Is a monoid type class with an operation isZero enought for your case?

Comment: @ChristopheCalvès perhaps... the example seems to be trying to fit a higher kinded type `Function[A, B]` into a lower kinded type parameter `M[A]`, whereas I'm trying to do the opposite, but perhaps the two issues don't work for the same reason.

Comment: @ChristopheCalvès I'm now convinced that the two issues are indeed related, thanks for pointing it out. I used `Unapply` to get around this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can use `Unapply` magic to convert a type of kind `*` to a type of kind `* -> *`.

Here's my solution:

```
def f[F[_]: IsEmpty, A](fa: F[A]): F[A] = fa

def fU[FA](fa: FA)(implicit U: Unapply[IsEmpty, FA]) =
  f[U.M, U.A](U(fa))(U.TC)
```

Now you can just do `fU("hello")`. The return type will also be correctly inferred as `String`.

As far as I know, you do need this auxiliary function, which is kind of a pain, but I guess that's the price to pay for the lack of [direct compiler support.](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712)

---

I got this idea when I realized there's an instance of `Applicative` for `String` and that you can do stuff like `"hello".replicateM(3)`.

I reified this expression like so:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

scala> universe.reify("hello".replicateM(3)).tree
res32: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Scalaz.ToApplicativeOpsUnapply("hello")(Unapply.unapplyA(Applicative.monoidApplicat
ive(Scalaz.stringInstance))).replicateM(3)
```

And `ToApplicativeOpsUnapply` revealed the secret behind the scenes:

```
implicit def ToApplicativeOpsUnapply[FA](v: FA)(implicit F0: Unapply[Applicative, FA]) =
  new ApplicativeOps[F0.M,F0.A](F0(v))(F0.TC)
```